# Fritz WLAN USB stick - Xlib/Xfree86 dev packages for installing Wine

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, wine

I have installed Ubuntu 10.4 and want to install the driver for my Fritz WLAN USB stick according to http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/fritz!wlan_usb_stick (German site... sorry). Now I am trying to install Wine for using the Windows drivers. Because I do not have a cable connection to the router, I downloaded some packages on a windows PC and used an USB stick to install them on linux. But now when doing `./configure` in the Wine dir I get this:

> configure: error: X development files not found. Wine will be built
>   without X support, which probably isn't what you want. You will need to install
>   development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 at the very least.
>   Use the --without-x option if you really want this.

Which packages do I need… and is there an easier way to install Wine? Like a version I don't have to build before installing? I am completely new to Linux…

Answer (score 2):

[Wine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wine) is already available as a package for Ubuntu. You should even be able to [click this button](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wine) [Install wine http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine) to install it if you're viewing this page in the default Ubuntu browser.

In general, to install software on Ubuntu, use the [Synaptic package manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) (launched from the System > Administration) menu. Search for the package named `wine`, mark it for installation, and click the “Apply” button.

You may need to first [enable the universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#Repositories) in the “Software Sources” application; this is a one-time thing. The [universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Universe) contains open-source applications that are not as integrated into Ubuntu as the main repository.

You won't need to do this for Wine since Ubuntu provides it (unless you find you need a very recent version), but in general, to compile a program from source, you'll need to install the [build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/build-essential) [Install build-essential http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/build-essential) package and a number of other packages whose name ends in `-dev`. For Wine, [xorg-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xorg-dev) [Install xorg-dev http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xorg-dev) should be enough.

Comment: Unfortunately wine is not listed in the Synaptic package manager.? The universe repository is enabled. Where can I download the xorg-dev without using linux and the packages.ubuntu.com website?

Comment: @Mirco It's strange that wine isn't listed. Did you update the package list after adding the universe repository? (It should happen automatically if you use the Software Sources application, but try doing it manually just in case.) What does the command `apt-cache policy wine wine1.2` show (please copy-paste the output into your question)? To install `xorg-dev` without going through the browser, select it and install it in Synaptic (like you'd do for any other package).

Answer (score 0):

As the error state, you need X development files which can be installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libx11-dev
```

If building 32-bit version on 64-bit machine and you'll get similar error:

> configure: error: X 32-bit development files not found.

then install X 32-bit development files:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev:i386
```

If you still have some missing dependencies, try:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep wine
```

In case when you don't need graphics mode, then configure as suggested:

```
./configure --enable-win64 --without-x --without-freetype
```